# session.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT) not working properly in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hql, hibernate-session

In Hibernate setting FlushModeType.COMMIT on session object should flush the persistence context only when we explicitly commit the transaction right?

Here I have set FlushModeType.COMMIT on session object and both query objects as well, so when I persist the new Student("newStudent","newAddress") it should be flushed after both the select queries are executed, but instead here first the insert query for the persist statement was executed and then both the select queries were executed.
Can anyone please explain why is it happening like this?

please feel free to correct me, if my understanding of the flushing topic is wrong.

**Entity Classes.**

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
public class Employee {

    public Employee(){

    }
    public Employee(String EmployeeName, String EmployeeAddress){
        this.EmployeeName =EmployeeName;
        this.EmployeeAddress =EmployeeAddress;
    }

    @Column(name="employee_name")
    String EmployeeName;

    @Column(name="employee_id")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int EmployeeId;

    @Column(name="employee_address")
    String EmployeeAddress;
    // all getter and setter methods and toString method.
}

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student {

    public Student(){

    }
    public Student(String studentName, String studentAddress){
        this.studentName=studentName;
        this.studentAddress=studentAddress;
    }

    @Column(name="student_name")
    String studentName;

    @Column(name="student_id")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int studentId;
    
    @Column(name="student_address")
    String studentAddress;
    // all getter and setter methods and toString method.
}
```

**Hibernate Configuration.**

```
import Entities.Employee;
import Entities.Student;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Environment;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
public class Configs {

    @Bean(name = "factory")
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){


        org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configuration=new org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration();
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder=new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();

        Properties properties=new Properties();
        properties.put(Environment.URL,"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/practiceHibernate");
        properties.put(Environment.DRIVER,"com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        properties.put(Environment.PASS,"root");
        properties.put(Environment.USER,"root");
        properties.put(Environment.CURRENT_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS,"thread");
        properties.put(Environment.SHOW_SQL,true);
        properties.put(Environment.DIALECT,"org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect");

        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Student.class).addAnnotatedClass(Employee.class);
        configuration.addProperties(properties);
        ServiceRegistry service=builder.applySettings(properties).build();

        SessionFactory sessionFactory= configuration.buildSessionFactory(service);

        return sessionFactory;

    }

}
```

**Main code.**

```
import Entities.Employee;
import Entities.Student;
import org.hibernate.FlushMode;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

import javax.persistence.FlushModeType;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context=new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Configs.class);
        SessionFactory factory=context.getBean("factory",SessionFactory.class);

        Session session=factory.openSession();

        session.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
        session.beginTransaction();

        session.persist(new Student("newStudent","newAddress"));

        Query<Employee> q=session.createQuery("select o from Employee o where o.EmployeeId>=1", Employee.class);
        
        q.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
        List<Employee> list= q.getResultList();

        for(Employee o:list){
            System.out.println(o);
        }
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

        Query<Student> q1=session.createQuery("select s from Student s where s.studentId>=15",Student.class);
        
        q1.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
        List<Student> list1= q1.getResultList();

        for(Student o:list1){
            System.out.println(o);
        }
        
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        factory.close();

    }
}
```

**output:**

> Hibernate: insert into student (student_address, student_name) values (?, ?)
> Hibernate: select employee0_.employee_id as employee1_0_, employee0_.employee_address as employee2_0_, employee0_.employee_name as employee3_0_ from employee employee0_ where
> employee0_.employee_id>=1
> Employee{EmployeeName='employee1', EmployeeId=1, EmployeeAddress='employee1Address'}
> Employee{EmployeeName='employee2', EmployeeId=2, EmployeeAddress='employee2Address'}

---

> Hibernate: select student0_.student_id as student_1_1_, student0_.student_address as student_2_1_, student0_.student_name as student_3_1_ from student student0_ where student0_.student_id>=15
> Student{studentName='student1', studentId=39, studentAddress='student1Address'}
> Student{studentName='student2', studentId=40, studentAddress='student2Address'}
> Student{studentName='newStudent', studentId=42, studentAddress='newAddress'}